# ffmpeg: How to save SSIM and PSNR to a file?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, ssim

I'm a ffmpeg newbie.
I would like my script (on Windows) to output the average PSNR and average SSIM values to a file.
(but not the values for every frame)
I can output them to the standard output but not to a file.

I use this line:

```
ffmpeg -i ref.avi -i compressed.avi -lavfi  "ssim;[0:v][1:v]psnr" -f null -
```

I understand I have to change something here: "-f null -" , but I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using ssim & psnr filters

On Linux and macOS you can use `grep`:

```
$ ffmpeg -i compressed.avi -i reference.avi -lavfi "[0][1]ssim;[0][1]psnr" -f null - |& grep Parsed_ > ff.log
```

Simple, but major downside is it won't show you the console output, so you may miss errors. To fix that add `tee`:

```
$ ffmpeg -i compressed.avi -i reference.avi -lavfi "[0][1]ssim;[0][1]psnr" -f null - |& tee >(grep Parsed_ > ff.log)
```

Example contents of `ff.log` from either command:

```
[Parsed_ssim_0 @ 0x5579d7f17b40] SSIM Y:0.796135 (6.906565) U:0.843488 (8.054531) V:0.822424 (7.506157) All:0.820682 (7.463768)
[Parsed_psnr_1 @ 0x5579d7f12b00] PSNR y:24.940925 u:23.938192 v:23.641771 average:24.138969 min:23.298059 max:26.880485
```

- If you want to append to `ff.log` instead of overwrite use `grep Parsed_ >> ff.log` instead.
- If `|&` does not work for you use `2>&1` instead.

## Or use libvmaf

[libvmaf](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#libvmaf) filter is slower but will output a log file containing the VMAF, SSIM, and PSNR aggregate scores along with the per frame scores in XML or JSON. Your ffmpeg will need to be compiled with `--enable-libvmaf` to use this filter.

```
ffmpeg -i compressed.avi -i reference.avi -lavfi "[0][1]libvmaf=log_path=vmaf.xml:log_fmt=xml:ssim=1:psnr=1" -f null -
```